# How to find the index of an element in an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Objects and I have an object

```
 var x = [{
     name: a,
     children: [{
         name: b,
         children: [{
             name: f
         }]
     }],
 }, {
     name: c,
     children: [{
         name: d
     }],
 }, {
     name: e,
     children: [{
         name: f
     }],
 }]
```

and now how can i find that 'f' is present in this object and can we find the path of it?

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: You need a recursive search. A very similar question has already been asked. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559286/find-an-element-in-an-array-recursively

Comment: @SamuelDavidson : Thanks man. One of my problem solved and i have learned about recursive search. But can i find the path of the element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214798/path-to-matching-key-value-pair-in-a-nested-object

Comment: You could store a list of the current parent objects or something. Then when you find the object you are looking for, that list will be your path.

Comment: @SamuelDavidson : Thanks bro. I will try it and thanks for your advise

Comment: No problem. Just remember to close your question or answer it yourself when you've found a solution you like. :)

Comment: @SamuelDavidson : Sure man