# Search recursively through a deeply nested object/array and collect values that include a specified string without knowing the key(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, traversal

Let's say I have a deeply nested object or array, returned from an API, which may look like this:

```
const array = [
  {
    key1: 'dog',
    key2: 'cat'
  },
  {
    key1: 'dog',
    key2: 'cat'
    key3: [
      {
        keyA: 'mouse',
        keyB: 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1'
        keyC: [
          {
            keyA: 'tiger',
            keyB: 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key4: 'dog',
    key5: 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'
  }
]
```

I want to traverse the object/array recursively and build an array of all the values that are strings and include the substring `https://myURL.com`, and building an array with the matches as follows:

```
let matches = [
   'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1',
   'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2',
   'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'
]
```

An important note is that I DO NOT know in advance what the relevant key(s) are. A value that is a URL could be on any key, potentially. So, in this example I cannot simply look for `keyB` or `key5` - I have to test every `key:value` pair for values that include a URL string.

**Question**

How do I create a recursive function to search the object for values that .includes() string 'https://myURL.com'? Happy to use a lodash method, so feel free to submit solutions that depend on lodash.

**Context**

The data comes from a CMS API and I will be using the array of URLS (`matches` above, in this example) to [add assets to cache with Cache API](https://web.dev/cache-api-quick-guide/), async in background, for offline functionality for a PWA.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51657359/6651840) and modify it a little bit

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen The problem I have is that is that I don't know what the possible names of the property keys in advance, so I essentially need to test every key:value pair for value that include a URL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursive function finds those leaf nodes that match a predicate:

```js
const getMatches = (pred) => (obj) =>
  obj == null ?
    [] 
  : Array .isArray (obj)
    ? obj .flatMap (getMatches (pred))
  : typeof obj == 'object'
    ? Object .values (obj) .flatMap (getMatches (pred))
  : pred (obj)
    ? obj
  : []


const array = [{key1: 'dog', key2: 'cat'},{key1: 'dog', key2: 'cat', key3: [{keyA: 'mouse', keyB: 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1', keyC: [{keyA: 'tiger', keyB: 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2'}]}]}, {key4: 'dog',key5: 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'}]

const check = val => typeof val == 'string' && val .includes ('https://myURL.com')

console .log (
  getMatches (check) (array)
)
```

We could modify it to also include the non-leaf nodes as well.  But this seems to be what you need for this case.

We simply pass it a predicate to test our node and pass to the resulting function an object or array you want to test.  It will return the matching nodes.

You can save the intermediate function, if you like, by simply not passing the object directly:

```js
const getMyUrls = getMatches (check)
// ... later
const urls = getMyUrls (someObject);
```

### Update

The answer from Thank you made me realize that my function could be further simplified.  This is a better version of it:

```js
const getMatches = (pred) => (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .values (obj) .flatMap (getMatches (pred))
  : pred (obj)
    ? obj
  : []
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic approach using a `values` and `filter` generator  -

```js
const values = function* (t)
{ if (Object(t) === t)
    for (const v of Object.values(t))
      yield* values(v)
  else
    yield t
}

const filter = function* (test, t)
{ for (const v of values(t))
    if (test(v))
      yield v
}
```

We can now write a simple `query` using `filter` -

```js
const myArray =
  [ ... ]

const query =
  filter
    ( v =>
        String(v) === v
          && v.startsWith("https://myURL.com")
    , myArray
    )

const result =
  Array.from(query)

console.log(result)
// [ 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1'
// , 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2'
// , 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'
// ]
```

---

Using generics like `filter` we can write specialised variants like `searchByString` -

```js
const searchByString = (test, t) =>
  filter                                     // <-- specialisation
    ( v => String(v) === v && test(v)        // <-- auto reject non-strings
    , t
    )
```

Now querying is cleaner at the call site -

```js
const myArray =
  [ ... ]

const query =
  searchByString                              // <-- specialised
    ( v => v.startsWith("https://myURL.com")  // <-- simplified filter
    , myArray
    )

const result =
  Array.from(query)

console.log(result)
// [ 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1'
// , 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2'
// , 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'
// ]
```

---

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
const myArray =
  [{key1:'dog',key2:'cat'},{key1:'dog',key2:'cat',key3:[{keyA:'mouse',keyB:'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1',keyC:[{keyA:'tiger',keyB:'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2'}]}]},{key4:'dog',key5:'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'}]
  
const values = function* (t)
{ if (Object(t) === t)
    for (const v of Object.values(t))
      yield* values(v)
  else
    yield t
}

const filter = function* (test, t)
{ for (const v of values(t))
    if (test(v))
      yield v
}

const searchByString = (test, t) =>
  filter
    ( v =>
        String(v) === v && test(v)
    , t
    )

const query =
  searchByString
    ( v => v.startsWith("https://myURL.com")
    , myArray
    )

const result =
  Array.from(query)

console.log(result)
// [ 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/1'
// , 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/2'
// , 'https://myURL.com/path/to/file/3'
// ]
```

Comment: You've been saying it for a while, but I finally realized how much your `Object (obj) === obj` formulation simplifies things.  The update in my answer really demonstrates it, by recognizing that `Object.values` unifies array and object processing, again, what you've been saying for a while, and I've just been missing it.

Comment: Thank you. Beautifully concise, but have awarded to Scott as he was first and also good answer.

Comment: Scott, tbh it's sad we're forced to read between the lines with `Object(t) === t`. As a dynamic language, I wish JS had a better api for runtime type checks. Eg `isObject(t)` or better `is(Object, t)`, `is(Array, t)`, `is(String, t)`, ...